# How to setup canon MF4720w to scan on ubuntu mate 16.10

Tags: drivers, printing, canon, mate, scanner

I need to setup my canon MF4720w printer and scanner. While I was able to install the printer drivers, I can't find any resource to setup a scanner.

I tried some tutorials online with libsane-extras. but none of them seems to work.

It seems even the printer doesn't recognize that it's connected to a computer.

How can I setup it's scanner?

OS: Ubuntu MATE 16.10

Comment: It is unclear to me whether you can print at this point or not. Would you please elaborate what you did, and what works and what doesn't.

Comment: @Dr_Bunsen print works. scanner doesn't. I've gone through some tutorials. but none of them seem to work with MATE.

Answer (score 0):

please tell us how the MF is connected to your computer; via usb, it should work as the SANE site says the MF4700 series have good support; if you type `lsusb` is the device listed as `04a9:2774`

for scanners to work over wireless, things get more complicated https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ScanningHowTo

and more specifically this https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SaneDaemonTutorial?action=show&redirect=sane.d+tutorial ........... they talk you through what you need to do

---

this is an imageCLASS device; I see some are already in **40-libsane.rules** which is in /lib/udev/rules.d/

eg `# Canon imageCLASS MF4270
ATTRS{idVendor}=="04a9", ATTRS{idProduct}=="26b5", ENV{libsane_matched}="yes"`

so if you are usb, one can create an entry there